# Restore a part of VM from snapshot in VMware ESXi

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I have a VM which is deployed in a ESXi. The VM has 2 virtual disk: disk1 and disk2. Then I created a snapshot for the VM. Is there anyway to only restore disk1 of VM (to the time snapshot was created), while not restore disk2? As I know, VMware ESXi use delta file to save snapshot, can I just delete the delta file of disk1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you delete the delta, you'll wind up in a world of hurt. Unfortunately, the snapshot is meant to be a restore point to that exact moment in time. If you need to rollback, then you'll have to do it with both disks. If you attempt just one, you'll likely have trouble with mounting the disk and will have to edit the VPX file to point back to the right disk. Then, you'll end up with an issue where you can't delete the snapshot of the second disk and consolidate it.

If you need a disk to be independent, you have to select that when you add the disk to the VM. Independent disks won't be affected by snapshots.